# Point in declaring the members of java.lang.Object with access privileges?

Tags: java, object

`clone()` and `finalize()` of the [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class are declared as `protected`.

Any point in this?

All java classes are inherently descendants of the class `Objects`-- there's no exception to this.

How would

```
protected void finalize()
```

differ in effect from

```
void finalize()
```

?

Comment: For your second question, [subclasses would not be able to access the members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) if they were declared without an access modifier, ie. they had default visibility.

Comment: Do you mean, how would `protected ...` differ from `public ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more subtle than you think. If class A and class B both extend class C, and class C has some protected members, then code in class A can't call those protected members via a variable of type B or C, and vice versa. A class can override a protected member and make it public. By making the members protected in class C, you give class B and class A the choice of whether to expose them.

Comment: Erm, they could if they were in the same package.

Comment: I think you mean "via an expression whose type is class B", rather than "on an instance of class B".

Comment: @Brian but in general, you can't define new classes in package java.lang.

Comment: @David Correct, edited.

Comment: Well ... no, but your reply is more generic than talking about just `Object`. That aside, where it makes a *real* difference is you can't call `.clone()` on an object referenced by a variable typed `Object` regardless of what that instance really is (and this is all ignoring that clone/clonable is terribly broken and should really be avoided, and it's unlikely most people will ever use `finalize()`, at least not correctly :) ).